# Can I use whole milk instead of powdered milk?

Tags: bread

I just received a bread machine and I wanted to make a loaf of bread but I don't have powdered milk. Can I use whole milk instead of powdered milk?

Answer (score 0):

Can you? Yes. But you will need to offset a liquid (water?) and powdered milk. You will need to work backwards from something like this: http://www.hillbillyhousewife.com/reconstituting.htm to remove X powdered milk and Y water to use Z milk.

Say your recipe called for 1 cup water and 1 1/2 tablespoon of powdered milk. Because one would normally use 1 1/2 tablespoons of powder with 1/4 cup water to get 1/4 cup milk (this may depend on the brand of powder, but this is a good general rule), working backwards you would remove 1/4 cup of water and replace that with whole milk, and then add 3/4 cup water.